# Google drive embedded video not showing in IE & Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, microsoft-edge

I am embedding videos from Google drive on a site and the videos appear fine in Chrome & Firefox. In IE 11 and Edge it's a no go. I am assuming this is a privacy setting in the browser, although I'm not sure which. Also, if it is a privacy setting this obviously will not work as I can't go into every user's settings for them! Solutions or work-arounds?

here is the iframe code I am using...

```
<style>
  .embed-container { 
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 100%; 
  } 
  .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    border:none;
  }
</style>
<div class="embed-container">
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8az0_GAjTu8WWZ4Q2RxX1RoZWc/preview"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working fine for me in IE9 < , Edge and all browser. check this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8Ltwket0/

Comment: screenshot: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/212760/4474881/gneqdvyWZw4VZpm/fiddle.jpg

Comment: It's throwing "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error.

Please refer to below question for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Please check your browser settings also.

Answer (score 0):

Check your compatibility view settings in IE. It works for me in IE when compatibility mode is turned off but when compatibility mode is turned on, it doesn't work. If that's the problem, you can either continue with compatibility mode turned off or you can also place the follow snippet of code in the head tag of your HTML to override user's compatibility view settings.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

Comment: my page is set to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: see http://app.tendesign.us/sites/ohio-cashflow/properties/eleanor-toledo as an example

Comment: I tested that site in both IE11 and Edge on my Windows 10 machine and I could play the video just fine. If it's still not working for you, I wonder if it's a setting on your machine. You could try resetting IE to defaults and testing again.

Comment: yea it must be a setting on my machine. thanks for your help!